# Update Variable On Hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am trying to have a variable that always matches the hash of the URL on a single page site.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hashTag = window.location.hash;
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        console.log(hashTag)
    });
});
```

Using the code above creates a list of all the past changes rather than the current hash.

```
hashTag.last();
```

This didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are attaching `button click` event listener again and again. Please move your button event listener outside `hashchange` event, like below

```
var hashTag = "";

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    hashTag = window.location.hash;
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    console.log(hashTag)
});
```

Now, there is permanent event listener attached to `button` which display value of `hashTag` variable. And on `hashchange` value of `hashTag` variable is updated.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!